# How to add experience editor button with Sitecore Powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I've created a script to aid editors publishing components on a page, and I've added it to the `content editor` item context menu, but I can't work out how to add a button to do the same from the `experience editor`.

I've added an integration point following the "**Experience button**" example here:

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/page-editor

But this adds a button to the floating menu you see when clicking on a component (I'm not sure what this is called - it has the component architecture tree navigation button, component `datasource` button, personalization etc).

What I'm trying to achieve is a button in the `Experience Editor` Home ribbon, preferably in the `Publish chunk`. Is there an integration point to do this?

Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 5.0.0.42513
Sitecore 8.2
Windows PowerShell 5.1

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for this? I'm architecting an idea at the moment and curious to see an implementation like this in the wild.

Comment: No, I didn't follow through with this, but I think you could probably stitch it together manually by creating the items in the core database